# Ubuntu 14.10 does not shut down on Acer Extensa 2509 notebook

Tags: boot, shutdown, acer, 14.10, acpi

I am currently running into a problem with my new Acer Extensa 2509 notebook. After installing Ubuntu 14.10 onto the hard drive, I was not able to shut down my live USB drive. After a hard reset, although all functionality worked, I still could not shut down the computer (neither by clicking on the regular shut down button, nor by entering `shutdown -h now` into the terminal).

At that point, just the Ubuntu splash screen was shown and at some point, the dots beneath the logo would not blink any more and the notebook CPU fan would start to spin at maximum for a few seconds periodically. Then it was only possible to press the power button for a few seconds to shut the computer down.

The booting worked fine until I followed what was supposed to be the solution to a similar problem, by removing the text for the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=””` inside the `/etc/default/grub file`. I tried `”quiet splash acpi=force”` before, which apparently did not make a difference. Now, after deleting the content in between the quotes, updating grub and restarting, I see no Ubuntu screen any more and while the first time, I was still able to boot up, now I can not even boot the machine any more.

It now shows these two screens: The first while booting up and the second while trying to shut down, still accompanied by the periodically running notebook fan.

Is there something in the displayed message that can relate to the problem and maybe a possible solution that I could try (except I might have to reinstall the system not anyways)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just thoughts...
I have equal problem with Fujitsu-Siemens AMILO Pro V3505, started at unnoticed moment of time (13.10 or 14.04). Upgrading to 14.10 did not solved the problem. Even the shutdown screen is similar to yours: after shutting down the ModemManager (do you have built-in dial-up modem?) system stuck on "Will now halt"

And it is not the installed system's fault: USB-HDD with installed 14.04 behaves equally, while works just fine on other PCs. (can't remember, if there's ModemManager installed on that HDD)

Preinstalled Windows XP Home (bootable via GRUB) shuts down/reboots the PC  correctly. It looks like something broken in ACPI control software.

When I tried REIUSB, REI all gave me "This function is disabled", while USB did what intended: emergency remount R/O, emergency sync and reboot.